# Overriding price-based shipping profiles with weight in Store

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I have this issue with Shipping costs.

We have 4 profiles setup

```
0-£100 - £6
£100 - £500 - £12
£501 - £4000 - £20
£4001+ - £25
```

The issue comes as we have a product that is in the £12 shipping price bracket however we only charge £6. Which we set a weight to compensate for this issue and it worked. But the issue comes when someone orders another product in £100 - £500 category. It still only charges the £6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which ecommerce add-on are you using? EE version?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. EE is 2.4.0
the store is Store *a fully featured commerce module for ExpressionEngine* Module 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution but it was for an issue I was having... Try adjusting your shipping rule thresholds to:

```
0 - £101 - £6 
£101 - £501 - £12 
£501 - £4001 - £20 
£4001+ - £25
```

Or some variation thereof.

---

Apparently the rules in Store are "exclusive of the high number...

So setting 0-£101 works for 0-£100... and £101 - £501 works for £101 - £500